# How to get predicted probabilities in competing-risk random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I want to use **randomForestSRC** to create a competing risk model (0 censored, 1 event of interest, 2 competing event). I want to **predict each persons probability for the event of interest** at different times.

Is the probability exactly the same as the cumulative incidence function (CIF)?

If that was the case, the following example would give probabilities

```
library(randomForestSRC)
data(wihs, package = "randomForestSRC")
wihs.obj <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., wihs, nsplit = 3, ntree = 100)

pred.obj = predict(wihs.obj)
probabilities = pred.obj$cif
```

And the corresponding time of interests that the CIFs are given are stored in

```
pred.obj$time.interest
```

**I would like to know whether these CIFs are actually the probabilities for the event.**

Answer (score 1):

We would refer you to the documentation and, in particular, the section on competing risks:

https://kogalur.github.io/randomForestSRC/theory.html#section8.2

There are two relevant ensembles produced: an estimate for the cause-specific cumulative hazard function (cs-CHF), and an estimate for the cause-specific cumulative incidence function (cs-CIF).  The predicted value for an event j is the integrated cause-specific cs-CIF. It can be interpreted as the expected number of life years lost, and is a measure of mortality.

Links to the specific definitions and reference to existing theory are included in the documentation.